# How can I prevent the scaling of a UIWebview's content after reorientation?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, screen-rotation

I'm building an iOS 5/6 app that has a UIWebView. It loads some HTML that I have embedded in my app.
Now when I rotate my device, the WebView changes its size (as I want it to fill the entire width of the screen).
And then it gets weird: some content gets scaled up and some content doesn't get scaled up. See this image with some example text in it:[image: UIWebview rotation issue]

As you can see, the header (H6) stays the same, while the paragraph gets scaled up. Does anybody have an idea how to prevent this? I want the html to look the same in landscape as it does in portrait mode.

I've tried setting the viewport scaling to 1: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,max-scale=1.0">` 
but that doesn't help. The body's `font-size` style is set to `14px`, but changing that to `14pt` or a percentage also made no difference. Setting the `width` of the body to `100%` also didn't help.

Strangely, removing the line break (`<br/>`) that's in the text fixes it but I need line breaks to be in there so that's no solution.

The only thing that *does* work is reloading the UIWebView's content after an orientation change, but that doesn't prevent it from looking wrong *during* rotation, and it resets any scrolling that the user may have done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it might be the scalesPageToFit propertie on your UIWebView.

Comment: That was one I had tried but not in combination with the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,max-scale=1.0">`. That meta tag is needed for the content to be shown at the right scale (and not scaled down to fit). This fixed my problem in most cases (and I'll grant you the bounty because it fixed the specific use case I mentioned in the question).

In one place I also had to put a `style="font-size:99.99%"` in a `div` in the html to prevent the paragraph text from scaling up.

Answer (score -1):

If you are coding on XCode (I assume that because you are using UIWebView)

- Choose the UIWebView on the nib.
- Ultilities pane > Size inspector > in the Autosizing box, remove both double-direction arrows.
- The UIWebView now has fixed size and won't automatically scale to orientation.

[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, but no, that's not what I want. I want the WebView to fill the width of the device so those red arrows inside the box need to be on. I want the content to stay the same size while the size of the box changes.